# How to convert datetime to string or double in powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to get a hint how to convert datetime -uFormat %T (for example 08:45:00) to double or a string like 8,75 hours.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = Get-Date
'{0:HH},{1:N0} hours' -f $date,($date.Minute/60*100)
```